# Linear layout click listener not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have linearlayout within linear layout two textviews and one listview vertically.I added click listener on linear layout and it's working but problem is,when I click on textviews uper side it's working but in middle and lower of linear layout click linstener not working because there is listview. I want to know that to handle this problem while I am not performing any on listview.

Please help me .
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use an itemclicklistener on the listview instead

Comment: @Xander I did this also but onItemClickListener not working because this layout is in getview in adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can set your listView not clickable in xml attribute, but the better option is to handle the click inside your listView or your listView's adapter just like you handle in the linearLayout.

Comment: because I am implementing nested list .This layout is in getview in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving answer of my own question.After a long Research and Development. I created a linear layout instead of  Listview. I created UI dynamically and pass it in to loop. And add them to linear layout dynamically. It's working fine.